# Usage of --gtest_throw_on_failure together with ASSERT_ANY_THROW in test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

During the execution of a unit test, I expect my program to fail an assertion and then crash.

My plan was to test that the programm effectively crashes given some conditions that I prepare with the test. For this, I wanted to use in my test ***ASSERT_ANY_THROW(statement_causing_crash);***.

and run my tests with the flag **--gtest_throw_on_failure**.

The result when running from the command line is:

1. The executable generated crashes when reaching the assertion (as expected)
2. A window pops up reporting the crash
3. In the command line, where I see the result of the tests, the line and reason of the fail is reported
4. The execution of the tests does not continue (the .exe crashed)

What is that, that I have not yet understood about the usage of **ASSERT_ANY_THROW** and **--gtest_throw_on_failure**?

I also don't want to see the window reporting the crash, because the tests should run automatically on a regular basis.

By the way, something else that I also tried, was to use **ASSERT_DEATH** instead of **ASSERT_ANY_THROW**, and it works better, because all the tests are executed.

Nevertheless, the .exe keeps crashing and I need to press *"Close the program"* so that the tests continue after the crash, which is really not good, because as I mentioned above, these tests run automatically, and many tasks depend on the result of the tests.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, because "crash" is a slang term that can
mean various different things. Edit your post to show example code or
actual code for *statement_causing_crash*.

Comment: Calls to the [`assert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) macro in application code are not guaranteed to throw.  In fact, they aren't guaranteed to do anything as they may do nothing in a release build.  What assert does in a debug build when the condition is false is implementation defined.  The implementation may terminate your process immediately, which means gtest can't catch an exception because none was thrown.  If you want to throw exceptions, then throw them explicitly.

Comment: You are right, there is no exception thrown. The process terminates and does not throw an exception. I will try to fake the assert() implementation to throw an exception and use it in my tests.

I have also been trying to master the use if ASSERT_DEATH, which actually works, the problem is that when the application terminates there is a window reporting that the .exe stopped working and  where you have to click "Close the program" so that tests continue their execution. This is really bad, because you cannot use this in an automated process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **ASSERT_ANY_THROW** is used to test if an exception is thrown from the code being tested. [Read this](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#exception-assertions).
- Executing the tests with the flag **--gtest_throw_on_failure** makes ***Google Test assertion failures*** to throw an exception. The idea behind this is that another testing framework will detect this exception and fail a test. Complete information [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#letting-another-testing-framework-drive).

In summary, **ASSERT_ANY_THROW** and the flag **--gtest_throw_on_failure** don't have anything to do with each other.

And by the way, using GCC I could not find a way to avoid the pop up windows and use **ASSERT_DEATH**. My solution to my problem was to fake the assert, and use it in my tests. My assert's fake throws an exception, which is detected by **ASSERT_ANY_THROW**.